# How to exclude certain package to compile in sbt?

Tags: scala, sbt, sbt-assembly, sbt-plugin

Considering there is a package in a module :

```
package com.example.apple
```

Is it possible to exclude that particular package of that module instead of commenting each individual files of that package one by one?

Say I have multiple modules as :

```
myProject/
   /module1
        /com.example
                  /somepackage1
                       file1.scala
                       file2.scala
                       file3.scala
                       ..........
                  /somepackage2
                       filep1.scala
                       filep2.scala
                       filep3.scala

   /module2
          /com.example
                     /somepackage3
                     /somepackage3



       
   /module3
       .......similarly
```

So here , if we can exclude `somepackage1` in our `built.sbt`, it would be great instead of commenting  `file1,file2,file3...`individually.
Considering that I dont want that package to not get compiled.

Comment: What do you mean? Do you have a module that you don't want to publish? Can you please elaborate your need?

Comment: Hi @TomerShetah , added an example

Comment: and not exactly a module, it was a package of a module

Comment: Pragmatically speaking, you could just delete the whole package directory. When you want it back, restore from version control.

Comment: If you separate it into two modules, you can exclude one. I didn't succeed to do what you are trying to.